# htaccess SSL redirect

Tags: .htaccess

Currently the coder has the following line in the .htaccess file:

RewriteRule ^registration$   registration.php

I understand what this means.

However I also want to redirect domain.com/registration to
https://domain.com/registration

Anybody know how I could achieve this? I do not want any other pages in the app to go to https://...

Regards,
Fiona

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that the traffic is not already coming in via HTTPS before your perform the rewrite otherwise you could end up with an infinite rewrite loop.

Assuming Apache 2.0 and above:

```
RewriteCond HTTPS off
RewriteRule ^/registration$ https://domain.com/registration.php
```

Comment: ok.. so that worked for me. However on successful registration the user I want the user to be transferred to: http://domain.com/registration/done.php

I think because of the jump from https to http - its not finding the page and is just reloading registration.php.

Any ideas? (It was working pre messing with .htaccess file)

Fiona

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
RewriteRule ^/registration$ https://domain.com/registration.php
```

Comment: Thanks Dominik. Now it just looks so simple!
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond` is necessary to prevent redirection loop. But sometimes `RewriteCond HTTPS off` is useless when Apache is behind Nginx.

I have met a case when I have to use another Apache variable:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Now, in 2023 is a good choice to serve all site over HTTPS but if you still want to redirect only one page, write

```
RewriteCond HTTPS off
RewriteRule ^/registration$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/registration.php
```

as shown above or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^/registration$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/registration.php
```

if your Apache is behind reverse proxy (Nginx, for example).